# UTF-8 and ASCII Issue using VBA to produce XML Document

Tags: excel, xml, vba, utf-8

I have an issue I've spent about a week researching. I have a binary macro enabled template that I use to produce a large XML file that many can use to load into a program on a server. I developed the code below that builds the .XML template and fills it out. It works great until Chinese or certain other international characters are used then the .XML file is unusable. Some international entries require these characters (but only a small percentage). Only columns 7 and 21 have this issue (j = 7 and j =21). I found out that the problem is a UTF-8 issue because VBA saves the text as ASCII. One character that fails is é but ç works just fine as does &,*, or (. If I open the .XML file with notepad everything looks identical to a working file created without the macro.

I have not found any code that seems to fit this problem. Specific code causing problem "sheet1.Cells(i, j)" when j = 21.

examples for j = 21 from test data:

Recog 1 12th SA Revenue-(주)대림코퍼레이션 건설정보지점

Recog 1 12th SA Revenue-LG엔시스(주)(LG N-Sys Inc.)

Recog 1 12th SA Revenue-関電システムソリューションズ株式会社

```vb
Sub tester()

y = 15785
alias = "alias"
Filename = "filename"
'above will connect to other code
sFilePath = "C:\Users\" & alias & "\Desktop\" & Filename & ".xml"
fileNumber = FreeFile
Open sFilePath For Output As #fileNumber

For x = 3 To 221
arr = Sheet7.Cells(x, 1)
Print #fileNumber, arr
Next x

Print #fileNumber, "<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount=" & Chr(34) & "24" & Chr(34) & " ss:ExpandedRowCount=" & Chr(34) & (y - 12) & Chr(34) & " x:FullColumns=" & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34)

For x = 223 To 248
arr = Sheet7.Cells(x, 1)
Print #fileNumber, arr
Next x

'NEW INPUT info on alias of poster

For x = 249 To 291
arr = Sheet7.Cells(x, 1)
Print #fileNumber, arr
Next x

typenum = "<Data ss:Type=" & Chr(34) & "Number" & Chr(34) & ">"
typestr = "<Data ss:Type=" & Chr(34) & "String" & Chr(34) & ">"

For i = 16 To y
Print #fileNumber, "<Row ss:AutoFitHeight=" & Chr(34) & 0 & Chr(34) & ">"

j = 1

Do
If j = 1 Then
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, j).value = "" Then
    j = 11
    Else
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell>" & typenum & Sheet1.Cells(i, j) & "</Data></Cell>"
    End If
Else

If Sheet1.Cells(i, j).value = "" Then
Else
    If j = 2 Or j = 3 Or j = 4 Or j = 8 Or j = 12 Or j = 20 Or j = 22 Then
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell ss:Index=" & Chr(34) & j & Chr(34) & ">" & typenum & Sheet1.Cells(i, j) & "</Data></Cell>"
    ElseIf j = 13 Then
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell ss:Index=" & Chr(34) & j & Chr(34) & ">" & typenum & Sheet1.Cells(i, j) & "</Data></Cell>"
    j = j + 1
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell ss:Index=" & Chr(34) & j & Chr(34) & ">" & typestr & "!" & "</Data></Cell>"
    ElseIf j = 14 Then
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell ss:Index=" & Chr(34) & j - 1 & Chr(34) & ">" & typestr & "!" & "</Data></Cell>"
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell>" & typenum & Sheet1.Cells(i, j) & "</Data></Cell>"
    Else
    Print #fileNumber, "<Cell ss:Index=" & Chr(34) & j & Chr(34) & ">" & typestr & Sheet1.Cells(i, j) & "</Data></Cell>"
    End If
End If
End If

j = j + 1
Loop Until j = 25
Print #fileNumber, "</Row>"
Next

For x = 292 To 435
arr = Sheet7.Cells(x, 1)
Print #fileNumber, arr
Next x

Close #fileNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you switch to UTF-16 as the XML document character encoding?

Comment: @TomBlodget No, I don't think that will work. The problem is due to VBA using ASCII coding while XML uses the much more modern UTF-8 coding. I am unable to use foreign characters within VBA unless I use the non-English version of VBA or add another reference to the library. Neither of these will work for the end user.

Comment: XML uses characters in the Unicode character set. However, to allow any document character encoding to be used, the syntax allows numeric character entity references for any Unicode codepoint. That syntax only uses characters that are common to virtually every character encoding. So, no, XML doesn't require UTF-8.

Comment: You can dynamically create a FileSystemObject, which supports writing UTF-16. Pretty sure every version of Office on Windows, if not Windows (>=7) would include the required libraries.

Comment: @tom Blodget I get that both ASCII and UTF-8 can represent characters as numeric entities. However, I have no idea how this would allow me to print Chinese or Arabic characters from VBA.

Comment: @TomBlodget Specifically how do I get VBA to accept all possible characters into it, do a number of calculations then print the result containing all possible characters to a text document?

Comment: VBA uses UTF-16. It doesn't have a problem with character values and manipulation; It's writing text files where it falls short. Again, if you don't want to use external XML libraries or ADO's UTF-8-capable library, I'd recommend FSO's.  And, no ASCII and UTF-8 are character encodings, nothing to do with XML's (and HTML's) syntax for numeric character entity references. So, FSO for UTF-16 or comlicated VBA code for XML numeric character entity references?

Answer (score 0):

No, not ASCII; It's the user's/system's default character encoding for non-Unicode text files. It varies from user to user, computer to computer and time to time. That's never what you want (except when it's exactly what you want.)

Given the constraint to not use external libraries, the most straightforward thing would be to write it with UTF-16 as the XML document character encoding since VBA uses UTF-16.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()   
    Open "t.xml" For Binary Access Write As #1
    WriteUtf16 1, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16' standalone='yes'?>" & vbCrLf
    WriteUtf16 1, "<root>"
    WriteUtf16 1, ChrW(&HD83D) & ChrW(&HDEB2) ' U+1F6B2 Bicycle '
    WriteUtf16 1, Cells(1, 1)
    WriteUtf16 1, "</root>" & vbCrLf
    Close #1   
End Sub

Sub WriteUtf16(ByVal FileNo As Integer, ByVal Text As String)    
    Dim I As Long
    For I = 1 To Len(Text)
        Dim codeUnit As Long: codeUnit = AscW(Mid$(Text, I, 1)) ' AscW gets first UTF-16 code unit '
        Dim lo As Byte: lo = codeUnit And &HFF
        Dim hi As Byte: hi = (codeUnit And &HFF00) / 256 And &HFF
        ' UTF-16LE '
        Put #FileNo, , lo
        Put #FileNo, , hi
    Next I
End Sub
```

Or, if you wanted to do the bit-shifting math to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8, you could.

Or, if you wanted to do the bit-shifting math to convert UTF-16 to codepoints, you could then pretend you are writing with the ASCII character encoding (since all 8-bit character encodings emit the same values for the C0 Controls and Basic Latin block), and for codepoints not supported by ASCII, write out the syntax for an XML numeric character entity reference (e.g. `&#xe9;`).